# ASP.NET MVC title in site.master

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to append a global title at the end of my asp.net `ContentPlaceHolder`. It does not show up, only whats in the view's title.

Eg.

Site.Master.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /> .::. My Website Name.</title>
</head>
```

Some mvc view:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Home
</asp:Content>
```

Actual Rendered title: `Home`.

Needed title: `Home .::. My Website`.

Anyone know what the cause of this is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn:

```
<head runat="server">
```

Into:

```
<head>
```

This is due to the title-tag being processed server-side. So either you append the text to the title on code-behind, or you turn the server-side feature off(as shown above), and do it in your design.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove `runat="server"` from your `head` element and everything will works.

Theres an article from Phil Haack blog that deals with your problem. i am looking to find it out...

[Here it is](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/03/tipjar-title-tags-and-master-pages.aspx)